# Do you like a "Lookup" table in your data models?

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

Do you like a "Lookup" table in your data models?

In designing a new data model, we can either have type, status, and other tables per entity, or all grouped together in one "Lookup" table.  Do you have a preference?  An argument for or against? E.g.

OPTION 1...

Table: Employee

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName  EmployeeStatusId  EmployeeTypeId  EmployeeGenderId
123         Bob           234               345             456
```

Table: EmployeeStatus

```
EmployeeStatusId  EmployeeStatusName
234               Active
235               Inactive
236               Other
```

Table: EmployeeType

```
EmployeeTypeId  EmployeeTypeName
345             W2
346             1099
347             Other
```

Table: EmployeeGender

```
EmployeeGenderId  EmployeeGenderName
456               Male
457               Female
458               Other
```

OPTION 2...

Table: Employee

```
EmployeeId  EmployeeName  LookupEmployeeStatusId  LookupEmployeeTypeId  LookupEmployeeGenderId
123         Bob           800                     803                   806
```

Table: Lookup

```
LookupId    LookupGroup     LookupValue
800         EmployeeStatus  Active
801         EmployeeStatus  Inactive
802         EmployeeStatus  Other
803         EmployeeType    W2
804         EmployeeType    1099
805         EmployeeType    Other
806         EmployeeGender  Male
807         EmployeeGender  Female
808         EmployeeGender  Other
```

Comment: Check this out: Common lookup tables are one of the top 5 database design mistakes https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/

Comment: It's a known anti-pattern and is called "one true lookup table". You shouldn't do it.

Comment: OPTION 2:- Now write the foreign key constraint that ensures that `LookupEmployeeStatusId` actually contains a valid employee status, rather than a gender...

Comment: FOREIGN KEY EMPLOYEE {LookupEmployeeStatusId} REFERENCES (SELECT LookupId FROM Lookup WHERE LookupGroup = 'EmployeeStatus').  Simple, no ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do declarative referential integrity with option #2 which is really the main benefit you get by declaring these tables in in the first place.