# SQL. How to check if inserted data contains value of correct group from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, typeorm

If have two general dictionary-like tables. One consists of categories and another one consists of categories items. Also I have a specific table that must be related to one of categories items of appropriate category. Here's example:

*Categories table*

```
id | title
-------------------
0  | payment type
1  | vehicle type
```

*Categories items table*

```
id | title      | category_id
-----------------------------
0  | hourly     | 0
1  | full time  | 0
2  | motorcycle | 1
3  | bus        | 1
```

*Employees table*

```
id | name | payment_type 
------------------------
0  | Mike | 1
1  | Josh | 0
2  | Anna | 1
```

So I need *Employees table*'s column *payment_type* could have only those *ids* from *Categories items* table which belong to *payment type* from *Categories* table

How could I do this in Postgres? And how could I do this using typeorm if possible?

Comment: Is this a schema that you own and could modify? The easy answer is to create separate parent lookup tables for each domain rather than making a single generic lookup table. In this example, you would end up with `payment_type` and `vehicle_type` as separate tables with two rows each.

Comment: Yeah, it's my pet project actually. But why will I end up with separate tables? I implemented it with triggers and it works nice

Comment: A [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102934/do-you-like-a-lookup-table-in-your-data-models) had some good discussion. In particular, it referenced [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) which lists the single lookup as the first anti-pattern to avoid in your models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple constraints are not enough for this condition. I think you will have to use a `function` and a `trigger`. Have a look @ the following article: [when-validation-is-not-enough-postgresql-triggers-for-data-integrity](https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/05/06/when-validation-is-not-enough-postgresql-triggers-for-data-integrity/)

I modified the example, and cooked up the following.

```
  CREATE FUNCTION validate_payment_type() returns trigger as $$
      DECLARE
        categoryid int;
      BEGIN
         categoryid := (select id from categories c inner join categories_items ci on c.id = c.category_id
         where NEW.payment_type = c.id);

        -- categoryid with zero is payment
        IF (categoryid != 0) THEN
          RAISE EXCEPTION 'Attempting to insert payment_type that has a category item that is not payment_type';
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
      END;
      $$ language plpgsql;

      CREATE TRIGGER validate_payment_type  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON Employees
      FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_payment_type();
```

**Note: I have not tested it on a live database so there may be some typos.**
Note2: You could change from `categoryId` to `categoryTitle` but you would need to change the query a bit, and use `varchar` instead if int.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was really helpful and I implemented triggers. By the way, how do you think is it good approach for db design?